# Where is `OperatorList.txt`?

Tags: operator

I've read from [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/help.html) about Help -> Operator Cheat Sheet, which apparently creates an `OperatorList.txt` file that I can read. But where is it and how do I see it? Sorry for being such a noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be found in the Text Editor, selectable from the bottom left of the 3D view.  You have to select OperatorList.txt from the list of open documents.

[image]

NB.  If you want the file to persist you have to save it as a .txt file (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>).

Comment: Ah I see, I couldn't find the list of open documents. Thank you!